# NullPointerException getting connection when deployed on mochahost shared server

Tags: java, mysql, spring, nullpointerexception

I just moved my **Spring application** which is running fine on localhost to a **shared web hosting server** on mochahost, and I'm seeing the below exception (truncated) in the root cause:

```
root cause

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'adDaoImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:288)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1074)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
(truncated)
```

and below that:

```
root cause

    java.lang.NullPointerException
        com.adsense.connection.MySqlDBPooling.getConnection(MySqlDBPooling.java:28)
        com.adsense.dao.impl.AdDaoImpl.setDataSource(AdDaoImpl.java:21)
        sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:588)
(truncated)
```

AdDaoImpl.java

```
@Repository
public class AdDaoImpl implements AdDao{

    Connection conn;

    @Autowired
    public void setDataSource(){
        try{
            conn = (new MySqlDBPooling()).getConnection();
        }catch(SQLException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    ...
    ...
}
```

MySqlDBPooling.java

```
package com.adsense.connection;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import javax.naming.*;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextListener;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

public class MySqlDBPooling implements ServletContextListener{

    private static DataSource ds;

    public MySqlDBPooling(){
    }

    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce){
        try{
            Context envCtx = (Context)(new InitialContext()).lookup("java:comp/env");
            ds = (DataSource)envCtx.lookup("jdbc/AdSenseDB");
            System.out.println((new StringBuilder("MySqlDBPooling is set to ")).append(ds.toString()).toString());
        }catch(NamingException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException{
        return ds.getConnection(); // getting NullPointerException here
    }

    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent servletcontextevent){
    }
}
```

Context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context antiResourceLocking="false" privileged="true" version="5.0">
    <Resource 
       name="jdbc/AdSenseDB"
       auth="Container"
       type="javax.sql.DataSource"
       removeAbandoned="true"
       removeAbandonedTimeout="30"
       maxActive="300"
       maxIdle="300"
       maxWait="1000"
       username="<username here>"
       password="<password here>"
       driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
       url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/adsense_adsense"/>
</Context>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>Adsense</display-name>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>com.adsense.connection.MySqlDBPooling</listener-class>
  </listener>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.css</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.js</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.jpg</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.jpeg</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.png</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.gif</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.ico</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Some points:

1. I have placed my jars (including mysql-connector-java-5.1.10.jar) at /WEB-INF/lib. On localhost, the mysqlconnector is placed in tomcat libs. But since this is a shared server, i have no access to tomcat libs. WEB-INF/lib might be a wrong place for mysql connector.
2. WEB-INF/lib might be a wrong place for placing libs. In my other app (not related to this) running on Amazon web server, I have placed all libraries in tomcat libs folder.
3. In context.xml, i even changed url to jdbc:mysql://domain.com:3306/adsense_adsense i.e. replaced localhost to actual domain, but that didn't help.
4. In MySqlDBPooling.java, if ds is null, why did it not throw NullPointerException earlier at

> System.out.println((new StringBuilder("MySqlDBPooling is set to
>   ")).append(ds.toString()).toString());

which is executed during server start (MySqlDBPooling class is added as a listener in web.xml)

Thanks for your attention.

James

EDIT:

It worked after I updated MySqlDBPooling.java as suggested (get datasource using Spring) by @JB Nizet to:

```
package com.adsense.connection;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextListener;

import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;

public class MySqlDBPooling implements ServletContextListener{

    private static DriverManagerDataSource ds;

    public MySqlDBPooling(){
    }

    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce){
        try{
            ds = new DriverManagerDataSource();
            ds.setDriverClassName( "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            ds.setUrl( "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/adsense_adsense");
            ds.setUsername( "USERNAME");
            ds.setPassword( "PASSWORD"); 
            System.out.println("Datasource is: "+ds.toString());
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException{
        return ds.getConnection();
    }

    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent servletcontextevent){
    }
}
```

Comment: It clearly says your DataSource ds is not getting instantiated and you are calling getConnection() on null reference.

Comment: I think problem relies here ds=(DataSource)envCtx.lookup("jdbc/NepalAdzDB");

Comment: Yes, DataSource ds is not getting instantiated, I get that because ds.getConnection is throwing NullPointerException. That's plain simple. But why is ds coming out to be null? The thing is, it works fine on localhost. Then whey's there a problem on third party server? I think there's something to do with JARs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you declare a DataSource in the context.xml, Tomcat tries to instantiate it using its own classloader, and not the classloader of the webapp. So the driver jar in WEB-INF/lib is not in its classpath and the driver can't be loaded.

The reason you don't see an NPE sooner is that the JNDI lookup probably fails with a NamingException. You should see the stack trace of this exception in the log, at deployment time.

Since you're using Spring, you could create the DataSource from Spring (using a stand-alone connection pool) instead of letting Tomcat create it. See http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#jdbc-datasource

Comment: In that case, can I define the path to lib folder somewhere in configuration files?

Comment: AFAIK, no. You must drop the jar in tomcat's lib directory.

Comment: But i'm on shared hosting, and have no access to tomcat directory. What other option do you see possible?

Comment: The one I wrote in my answer: use DBCP or another pool implementation, put he pool's jar into WEB-INF/lib along with the DB driver, and use Spring to create a DataSource.

Comment: +1 as the answer is along the lines of "When using Spring's JDBC layer, you can either obtain a data source from JNDI or you can configure your own, using an implementation that is provided in the Spring distribution. The latter comes in handy for unit testing outside of a web container." at http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/1.2.x/reference/jdbc.html which I wouldn't have found without your answer. I hope this works out well. Testing...

Answer (score 0):

Your `dataSource` is `null`, May be class was reloaded by classloader

Answer (score 0):

It's simple, you're doing a `new MySqlDBPooling()` on `AdDaoImpl`. Seeing that MySqlDBPooling is already configured in `web.xml`, My guess would be that the Naming Context is not loaded by the classloader or the `Context.xml` is never read. Debugging and seeing if the datasource is instantiated when `contextInititated` is called would be a step.

Comment: Read the question carefully: he already did that, and although he uses a new MySqlDBPooling, the ds field is a static field.

Comment: It is there. MySQLDBPooling class is executed when server starts, and a DataSource Object is populated. Later, during autowire for connection, another method of MySQLDBPooling, getConnection() is called again to get connection from the Datasource object. It's all working fine on localhost. The problem is arising on third party hosting server (mochahost) only.